# Authentication issue in Google Cloud Client Library

Tags: php, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am setting up the google cloud client library from the below url:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-php

I have created a key from the given url:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/

[image]

and set it up in the environment variable.

but i am getting the below error:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: I have the same issue... don't know how to fix this... :)

Answer (score 0):

it work on command prompt something like:

```
php yourphpfilename.php
```

also you have an alternate way to pass the key file:

```
$credentialsFile = '[PATH_TO_JSON_KEY_FILE]';

# Instantiates a client
$bigquery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId,
        'keyFilePath' => $credentialsFile
]);
```

Hope it will help you.